# Facebook messenger chat item animation on click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, kotlin, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to make my list item to be animated after onClick(),Like Facebook messenger. I tried to do this with **animateLayoutChanges=true** in my list item layout and also my recyclerView's parent layout, but it is not smooth and have some problem, after first click when I want to show hidden fields (**setVisibility(VISIBLE**)) , it works not bad, but setVisibility(GONE) works not properly, this is what it looks like
[image]

**And what I'm trying to achieve is this**

[image]

Any advice how to do that?
this is My custom view

```
class MessageItemView : RelativeLayout {

  constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
  constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

  private var messageTextView: TextView
  private var dateTextView: TextView
  private var itemView: View? = null
  init {
      itemView =  LayoutInflater.from(context)?.inflate(R.layout.live_chat_list_item, this)
      messageTextView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.live_chat_msg_text_id) as TextView
      dateTextView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.message_received_date_txt_id) as TextView
  }

 fun setUPViewModelData(message: MessageModel) {
     itemView?.setOnClickListener {
         dateTextView.visibility = if (dateTextView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
         delivered_status_txt_id.visibility = dateTextView.visibility
  }
}
```

And this is xml of this view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_received_date_txt_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_wrapper_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/message_received_date_txt_id"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/live_chat_msg_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delivered_status_txt_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/message_wrapper_layout_id"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't understand what's wrong in my layout hierarchy or what would be good architecture and also interested in Fb's messenger chat item layout hierarchy... Any eideas?

Comment: Can you please post code for visible and gone ?

Comment: It's just calling method setVisibility(GONE) or VISIBLE

Comment: Yes but need code to check how you handle it for each item in adapter.

Comment: view.setVisibility(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? GONE : VISIBLE)

Comment: My list item is custom view and click listener is inside

Comment: Please post more code as @Haresh Chhedelana mentioned, I've had the same issue but it had to do with the RecyclerView.

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili Have you develop this on native ?

Comment: Used language is Kotlin

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili Okay is there any reason to use RelativeLayout as parent?

Comment: yes I need message_wrapper_layout_id to be changed its alignment programatically

Comment: But if the problem is inside RelativeLayout I can ignore that alignment

Comment: I think LinearLayout is okay for your current requirement as currently you have provide gone view ref to message_wrapper_layout_id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139474/discussion-between-jemo-mgebrishvili-and-haresh-chhelana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the animateLayoutChanges from your layout and then use the TransitionManager from the support library:

```
fun setUPViewModelData(message: MessageModel) {
     itemView?.setOnClickListener {
         TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView)
         dateTextView.visibility = if (dateTextView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
         delivered_status_txt_id.visibility = dateTextView.visibility
    }
}
```